# Use the fact that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $101$ to find all solutions to $x^7\equiv-2\pmod{101}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Use the fact that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $101$ to find all solutions to $$x^7\equiv-2\pmod{101}.$$

My number theory book says to compare powers of $2$ to $101$ to express $-2$ as a power of $2$ modulo $101$. I have computed powers of $2$ up to $40$ where my calculator loses accuracy so I have to assume there is some trick that I'm missing. I have read all through this chapter but I cannot find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Justify the following steps. All the arithmetic done in the group $\Bbb{Z}_{101}^*$ that is now given to be cyclic of order $100$ with generator $2$:

1. Because $-1$ is the only element of order two we must have $2^{50}\equiv-1$.
2. Therefore $2^{51}\equiv -2$.
3. Therefore $x=2^t$ is a solution of $x^7\equiv-2$ if and only if $2^{7t}\equiv 2^{51}\pmod{101}$ if and only if $$7t\equiv 51\pmod{100}.$$

Because $7$ is coprime to $100$ there will be a unique residue class modulo $100$ of acceptable value of $t$. I trust you have studied linear congruences earlier, and solving for $t$ poses no problem to you. Then you just need to calculate $x=2^t$.

Comment: oh thank goodness. The only part of this I'm having trouble understanding is where 2^50 came from

Comment: @JakeRyan34 If you have covered pieces about cyclic groups you may recall the rule that in a cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $c$, the order of $c^k$ is $n/\gcd(n,k)$. Here $n=100$, and you want order two, so that forces $k=50$.

Comment: Also, you may need to use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to get the remainder of $x=2^{93}$ modulo $101$. Alternatively you can run extended Euclid's algorithm, because $$x^{-1}=2^{100-93}=2^7=128\equiv 27.$$ So $x$ is the modular inverse of $27$.

Comment: Sorry I'm really trying to understand this. We want order two because the primitive root is 2?

Comment: No. We want order two because $-1$ has order two in this multiplicative group (and many others!). After all $(-1)^2=1$. Here we really wanted to write  $-2$ as a power of $2$ because that was needed to solve first $t$ and then $x$. Because writing $2$ as a power of two is easy, I used this trick to figure out a way of writing $-1$ as a power of two, and took advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

Using discrete logarithm

$7$ind$_2x\equiv 1+\dfrac{\phi(101)}2\pmod{100}\equiv51\equiv-49$

$\implies$ind$_2x\equiv-7\pmod{100}\equiv93$ as $(7,100)=1$

$\implies x\equiv2^{93}\pmod{101}$